# Unix-style password readline

Tags: crystal-lang

I understand how to read a string from STDIN (noted below), but my problem is that the characters are displayed on the screen. How can I make the string hidden like the Unix/Linux password prompts?

```
print "Password: "
pass = gets.as(String).strip
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard library currently provides no way for this. A quick workaround is to bind `getpass(3)`:

```
lib LibC
  fun getpass(prompt : Char*) : Char*
end

def getpass(prompt : String)
  password = LibC.getpass(prompt)
  raise Errno.new("getpass") unless password
  String.new(password)
end

password = getpass("Enter password: ")
```

However note that this function is deprecated by glibc and the `termios(3)` interface should be used. I opened a [pull request](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/3035) for this, so hopefully in Crystal version 0.19.0 or later you'll be able to:

```
print "Enter password: "
password = STDIN.noecho &.gets.try &.chomp
puts
```

Comment: And until 0.19.0 you can reopen IO and add that code, so you can use it right away :-)